# How can i set default time to current time mongo schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, ejs

I have been using Mongoose & EJS to make a dynamic blogs webpage.

I am trying to set a default time in my mongo schema to keep it in the database.

**Inside My Node file**

```
   var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,

},{timestamps: { createdAt: true }});
```

**Inside my EJS File**

```
<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
 <div>
     <h2><%=blog.title%></h2>
     <img src="<%= blog.image %>">
     <span><%= timestamps.createdAt %></span> //Error Here
     <p> <%= blog.body %></p>
 </div>
```

it keeps telling me that there is an error which says **timestamps is not defined** the error is on line 7 I marked it with a comment.

I tried reading the docs and do what it says but it won't work or I don't know what to do

[Mongo Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it gets, in your ejs, it should be `blog.createdAt` simply because you are not customising the name of the `createdAt` field. Also, you're looping inside `blogs` wherein each timestamp of `createdAt` exists inside the `blogSchema`, thereby it can be accessed using `blog.createdAt`.